# "logical subject" of verbals

Tags: subjects, participle-clauses, infinitive-clauses, gerund-clauses

Native speakers, could you please define "**logical subject**" of **verbals** (infinitive, gerund, participle)? I am Chinese and some of my grammar books define  "logical subject" as the **agent** of the action, while some define it as the **agent or patient** of the action.

Comment: I'm not a native speaker, but I suspect that the books that define it as the agent focus only on the canonical cases. (Passive clauses are non-canonical.) And those that define it as either the agent or the patient consider all possible sentences in general.

Answer (score 3):

> I don't like him using swear words.

In the above sentence the verb like has an object that is a gerund phrase 
"him using swear words".
The gerund phrase contains a full sentence "He uses swear words".
So some authors use the formulation "gerund construction with an own logical subject".
Of course, "him" is no subject in the sentence. Only if you transform the gerund phrase back to an independent sentence "him" becomes the subject "he". This is why "him" is called "logical subject of the gerund phrase".

This is the use of the term as I know it from my grammars. I never came across another use of the term. But it may well be that in some grammars the term is used in a different way, especially in Chinese grammars of English.

Comment: Thank you. In the sentence, "He was responsible for the luggage having been lost" is luggage the logical subject of the gerund phrase "having been lost"?

Comment: Yes, I would say so as you can transform the gerund phrase into "The luggage has been lost".

Answer (score 1):

For the non-linguist, *subject* is the definition of *agent or patient* rather than the other way round. Let's look at two sentences with a finite (*a form that shows the tense and subject of a verb*, http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/finite) form of the verb.

1. ***I*** beat John.
2. ***John*** was beaten.

In both sentences, the first word (in bold) is the grammatical subject, but in (1) **I** is the *agent* (*the doer of the action denoted by the verb*, Oxford English Grammar), and in (2) John is the *patient* (*a semantic role taken by a noun phrase which is acted upon or affected by the verb*, OEG).

Now let's move on to consider two sentences with non-finite verbs:

3. ***I*** wanted TO BEAT John.
4. ***John*** wanted TO BE BEATEN.

The non-finite verb forms (in brackets) do not, by definition, have a grammatical subject, However, the 'logical subject' of these two verbs is the same as the grammatical subject of the finite verb forms. In (3) the logical subject is the agent; in (4) the logical subject is the patient.

So, the logical subject of non-finite verb forms is the of  agent or patient of such verb forms.